# Как правильно вызвать метод?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Есть класс для сортировки процессов:

```
public class SortByProcessName : IComparer<Process>
{
    public int Compare(Process p, Process q)
    {
       return p.ProcessName.CompareTo(q.ProcessName);
    }
}
```

в другом классе я вызываю `Compare` , но можно ли вызывать так?

```
var pro = Process.GetProcesses();
Array.Sort(pro, new SortByProcessName());
```

или же лучше делать так?

```
SortByProcessName st = new SortByProcessName();
Array.Sort(pro, st.Compare);
```

Какой способ лучше использовать?

Comment: В принципе, это дело вкуса. Можно без создания отдельного класса: `Array.Sort(pro, (p1, p2) => p1.ProcessName.CompareTo(p2.ProcessName));`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, не знал что так можно) спасибо

Comment: "Какой способ лучше использовать?" Для этого нужно ответить на один простой вопрос: понадобится или нет повторное использование кода. Если не понадобится -- используйте анонимную функцию (не нужно будет придумывать ей имя). И оформили бы сразу ответом, а не комментарием.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без разницы. Оба способа будут использовать один и тот же метод Compare.

Все дело в удобстве использования. Именно поэтому метод Array.Sort имеет столько перегрузок (разные наборы параметров).

Например, можете в классе SortByProcessName метод Compare сделать статическим и тогда вам вобще не нужно будет создавать экземпляр класса SortByProcessName:

```
Array.Sort(pro, SortByProcessName.Compare);
```

Можете создать статический класс, реализующий кучу обобщенных интерфейсов IComparer и, соответственно, в нем реализовать все нужные вам алгоритмы сравнения. Как вам удобнее.

Comment: Возьму на вооружение)